# Linux (Debian) PHP USB Serial

Tags: php, linux, usb

I am trying to connect to `Ent Tec USB PRO` and receive data from a DMX controller (Obey 10).

**Looks to be connected**

```
[260650.393279] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[260658.258766] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

**usb-devices**

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  8 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0403 ProdID=6001 Rev=06.00
S:  Manufacturer=ENTTEC
S:  Product=DMX USB PRO
S:  SerialNumber=EN211058
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=300mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=ftdi_sio
```

**# lsmod | grep  ftdi_sio**

```
ftdi_sio               53248  0
usbserial              49152  1 ftdi_sio
usbcore               249856  9 usbhid,ehci_hcd,ohci_pci,ftdi_sio,usbserial,xhci_pci,ohci_hcd,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
```

**PHP** - Comm() --> https://github.com/Xowap/PHP-Serial

```
$serial = new \SerialClass\Comm();
$serial->Comm();
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyUSB0");
if (!$serial->_device) {
die("Connection failed");
}
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->confCharacterLength(8);
$serial->confStopBits(1);
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->deviceClose();
$serial->deviceOpen();
stream_set_timeout($serial->_dHandle, 5);

while ($connection_ok) {

    echo "#" . $iterations;

    $str   = $serial->readPort();

    echo "<BR><BR>Str: " . $str;

    if ($iterations++ > 1) {
        $connection_ok = FALSE;
        $serial->deviceClose();
        die("<BR><BR>DONE");
    } else {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

It is running without any errors. I have an ssh with `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`, which does not show anything.

**Output** - not very exciting...

```
#0

Str: 
#1

Str: 
#2

Str:

DONE
```

A note, there is light on the `DMX USB PRO` that blinks on standby. When I use it with my Windows box it blinks rapidly when transmitting data. When I run the PHP script on Debian the light goes out.? Could this be a driver issue?

https://www.enttec.com/us/products/controls/dmx-usb/dmx-usb-pro/

`# lsof | grep /dev/ttyUSB0` does not return anything.

I am not sure what to try next?
If anyone has any suggestion I would appreciate it.

**Addtitions:**

`mkaatman` - thank you for the suggestion.

The PHP log path `error_log = /var/log/php/errors.log` is not returning any errors either.

`Pascal Meunier` - thank you for the suggestion.

I tried using the baud rate and stop bits, unfortunately there is no difference.

Ent Tec - Suggests a 9600 baud and 1 stop bit. This works well on a windows. I will try all the main ranges to be sure.

**No solution found**

I created a c++ app instead, the input is working well with it.

Comment: Apache error log may or may not contain PHP errors. Run phpinfo(); to find the php error log or if you're running this script through cli you can do `php -i | grep error_log` I believe.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this project, specially the baud rate (250000) and stop bits (2). https://github.com/wiedi/node-dmx/blob/master/drivers/enttec-usb-dmx-pro.js